# Interferometry works as a filter

Tags: astronomy, astrophysics, observational-astronomy

I attended an astronomy seminar the other day and though I did not pick up much as it was on data collection etc, I did take away one sentence: "Interferometry works as a filter"

Now I know what interferometry is, it is a technique that is used to obtain the resolution of a large telescope by using multiple smaller telescopes. So where does the role of a 'filter' come in?

Comment: the quote is mentioned out of context, it may mean a number of things, if you can add the whole relevant passage or context into which this was mentioned, will make an answer easier and to the point

Answer (score 2):

An interferometer selects (filters) certain wave lengths and suppresses the others.